# Can I have a typehint for array of SomeObject when using list?

Tags: php, phpstorm, type-hinting

I have a method generating an array of `SomeObject[]`.

```
/**
 * @return SomeObject[]
 */
private function thatMethod()
{
    ...
    return [$someObject, $someOtherObject, $yetAnotherObject]
}
```

Yet when I read the object via `list`

```
list($someObject, $someOtherObject, $yetAnotherObject) = $this->thatMethod();
```

I lose typehint for those objects. I have to typehint them explicitly via `@var SomeObject $someObject`. I rather not do it this way.

Is there a way to get typehints working when using `list` in PhpStorm9?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PhpStorm cannot do such thing at the moment.

There is a the [ticket](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-20192) to look after. Star/vote/comment to get notified on progress.

Comment: Created by Dmitriy Zavalkin 24 Sep 2013 12:32